# Netbeans faces-config PROBLEMS

Tags: java, xml, jsf, netbeans, faces-config

I have a weird problem with my faces-config.xml file - I'm using Netbeans.

As soon as I make a faces-config file by choosing "New" -> "JSF Faces Configuration" the entire app fails at runtime: "The module has not been deployed."
When I erase the config file the app runs just fine (except for missing all the extra modifications from the faces-config file).
I'm using a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion. I use Eclipse on a daily basis and have all the necessary Java tools installed - as far as I'm concerned.

I appreciate any help. This problem has been going on for some time now and I can't find any matching case on the web.

HELP!!!

Comment: Maybe you're creating a faces-config that points to a different version of the JSF framework you're using in your code, i.e. JSF 2.x and faces-config for JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "except for missing all the extra modifications from the faces-config file"?  Did you put some manual configurations in this file?  Also, have you tried a clean and build before running the app after adding the new faces-config file?

Comment: Missing modifications meaning: I made some navigation rules, messages and so on. I have tried clean and build several times, but without any success. I just found out that when I make a whole new project and add a config file, everything works fine. As soon as I start an older project with a config file, the old one will fail...

Comment: I solved the problem myself. Problem is, I could only have one faces-config file at the time, although they were placed in different projects: by accident, somewhere I must have chosen that the config file should be shared among all projects. So when I made several the build failed. I think it's when you make a new project and choose "Enable Contexts and Dependency Injection".

Comment: Choosing that option only creates an empty beans.xml file for you, but it's good you figured it out : )

Comment: @ Jordan: Hahaha! Yeah, well... as you can see, Netbeans is total new to me :-) And the the problem hasn't been solved. It just came again! But now old projects with JSF config files work...